# How to avoid nesting promises in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I'm using [this tutorial](https://miningbusinessdata.com/dialogflow-firebase-tutorial/) as a main way to learn about Dialogflow and Firebase, and I've gotten stuck in the following section of code:

```js
25   if(action === 'firebase.update'){
26          let userId = 'marc.tuinier';
27          // Check if the user is in our DB
28          admin.firestore().collection('users').where('userId', '==', userId).limit(1).get()
29              .then(snapshot => {
30                  let user = snapshot.docs[0]
31                  if (!user) {
32                      // Add the user to DB
33                      admin.firestore().collection('users').add({
34                          userId: userId
35                      }).then(ref => {
36                          sendResponse('Added new user');
37                      });
38                  } else {
39                      // User in DB
40                      sendResponse('User already exists');
41                  }
42              });
43      }
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
 28:9   error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
 31:17  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
 33:21  error    Expected catch() or return                  promise/catch-or-return
 33:21  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
 35:29  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return
```

I was predominantly wondering how to fix these errors (and perhaps some material so I can learn more about it - thanks in advance!)

Comment: I suggest doing a search for each one of those lint messages to read about the type of possible error your code might have.  You have three distinct types of errors here.

Answer (score 2):

So as far as avoiding nested promises I would recommend looking into async / await, leaving you with something like the following. You can then add try/catch blocks to debug further

```js
if(action === 'firebase.update'){
       let userId = 'marc.tuinier';
       // Check if the user is in our DB
       let snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('userId', '==', userId).limit(1).get()
       let user = snapshot.docs[0]
        if (!user) {
            // Add the user to DB
            await admin.firestore().collection('users').add({
                userId: userId
            })
            return sendResponse('Added new user');
        } else {
            return sendResponse('User already exists');
        }
   }
```

Comment: Hey Richard, it got me a little further but the issues now lies in parsing the trigger function. Its having trouble with "await" and "admin."

Comment: ```Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

/Users/marctuinier/Voice App Project/functions/index.js:28
        let snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').where('userId', '==', userId).limit(1).get()```

With ^^^^^ under await. So I went for `async`, and then it gave the same error at `admin.`.